# complex default values for powershell script Params

Tags: powershell

I would like to set a default `Param` value that must be determined at script runtime (cannot be hardcoded).

Given powershell script `file.ps1`

```
<#
.PARAMETER arg1
    The first argument. Defaults to ???
#>
Param (
    [string] $arg1,
)
```

I would like:

1. Set `$arg1` to a value that must be determined when the script runs, for example, the host IP address.
2. Print the default value of `$arg1` within the `.PARAMETER arg1` help message.

Typically I might add

```
$arg1_default = (Test-Connection -ComputerName "www.google.com" -Count 1).Address.IPAddressToString

<#
.PARAMETER arg1
    The first argument. Defaults to $arg1_default.
#>
Param (
    [string] $arg1 = $arg1_default,
)
```

However, in Powershell, the `Param` statement must be the first processed statement. If I add any complex statements before `Param` statement then it results in an error:

```
PS> .\file.ps1
Param: file.ps1:9
Line |
   9 |  Param (
     |  ~~~~~
     | The term 'Param' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the
     | name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How do I set default values for a powershell script `Param` ?

I'm using Powershell 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `function` with [[CmdletBinding()]](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7) attribute like `Toto` in the file `test.ps1` defining a default value for a particular parameter for this CmdLet with  [$PSDefaultParameterValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7)

```
# Test.ps1    
$PSDefaultParameterValues["Toto:arg1"]=Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {(Test-Connection -ComputerName "www.google.com" -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString}
Function Toto
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param ([string] $arg1)
  Write-Output $arg1
}
```

Now in the script where you want to use this (or these) function(s) you can first *dot source* the`.ps1` file that contains the function(s), then call your function toto

```
. /Test.ps1
Toto  # without argument gives "172.217.18.196" for me now
Toto titi  # With argument give "titi"
```